# How can I create this logo without using an actual image with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created this logo in Photoshop, but I thought I could make this with html and CSS, I've tried to create it how I thought I could but I want to have it on the right hand side of my site but the `p` tags have a large width and it made the scroll bars appear, which I don't want. How can I create this logo while keeping it on the right hand side of my site with no scroll bars?

please view in full page to see the logo

```css
  html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* W3C */
  }
  
  ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 120px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  }
  
    
  ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 40px;
  }
  
  a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  }
  
 a:hover {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: url(images/dot.png) top center no-repeat;
  color: lightgrey;
  }
  
  .main_logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;  
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
  }

.largetext {
 font-size: 8em;
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 
}

#logo_text {
    position: relative;
    bottom:200px;
    left: 150px;
}

#logo_text p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 12px;
}
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 568px) and (max-width: 1024px){
   .main_logo {
    top: 150px; 
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 150px;
    }
   
    #tag {
     height: 70px;
     top: 0px;
     left: -20px;
    }
   
    #tag2 {
     left: 150px;
     top: 0px;
    }
   
    #logo_text {
   top: 70px;
   left: 70px;
   font-size: 0.7em;
   
    }
    
    ul li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    
    ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 490px;
    line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: url(images/dot_medium.png) top center no-repeat;
    }
    }
```

```html
   
<body>
 <div class = "main_logo">
 <p class = "largetext"><&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;></p>
            <div id = "logo_text">
   <p>John Smith</p>
            <p>Web Designer/Developer</p>
   </div>
        </div>
 </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the logo you created in Photoshop?

Comment: Use an SVG. There's really no need to overthink it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to `#logo_text`. It's block level by default, which when pushed over will cause the scroll bar to appear.:

```css
  html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #73C8A9 10%, #373B44 90%); /* W3C */
  }
  
  ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 120px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  }
  
    
  ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 40px;
  }
  
  a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  }
  
 a:hover {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: url(images/dot.png) top center no-repeat;
  color: lightgrey;
  }
  
  .main_logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;  
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
  }

.largetext {
 font-size: 8em;
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 
}

#logo_text {
    position: relative;
    bottom:200px;
    left: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#logo_text p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 12px;
}
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 568px) and (max-width: 1024px){
   .main_logo {
    top: 150px; 
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 150px;
    }
   
    #tag {
     height: 70px;
     top: 0px;
     left: -20px;
    }
   
    #tag2 {
     left: 150px;
     top: 0px;
    }
   
    #logo_text {
   top: 70px;
   left: 70px;
   font-size: 0.7em;
   
    }
    
    ul li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    
    ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 490px;
    line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: url(images/dot_medium.png) top center no-repeat;
    }
    }
```

```html
   
<body>
 <div class = "main_logo">
 <p class = "largetext"><&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;></p>
            <div id = "logo_text">
   <p>John Smith</p>
            <p>Web Designer/Developer</p>
   </div>
        </div>
 </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah that worked! what is this doing? thanks

Comment: It might be worth encoding the `<` (in `<&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;>`) to give `&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;>` (if not, the perhaps unnecessary, `&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;`)...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using a couple of pseudo elements

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6z1j1d1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo_text">
    <p>John Smith</p>
    <p>Web Designer/Developer</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo_text {
    position: absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:250px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
#logo_text:before, #logo_text:after {
    font-size:7em;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-100%, -50%);
}
#logo_text:before {
    content:"<";
    left:0;
    transform:translate(-100%, -50%);
}
#logo_text:after {
    content:">";
    left:100%;
    transform:translate(0%, -50%);
}
#logo_text p {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: ah I forgot a pseudo classes! I love the fact that there are so many ways of doing a single thing in CSS! thanks